# Shorthand definition for "stacked function"

Tags: calculus

I need some notation for slides; is there a convention to denote the following in a more compressed way?

$$ F(x) = \begin{cases}\underline F(x) & \text{if } x \leq \tilde x \\ \bar F(x) &\text{if } x > \tilde x\end{cases}$$

I was hoping that if I defined $\underline F(x)$ for the domain $[0, \tilde x]$, and $\bar F(x)$ for the domain $(\tilde x, \infty)$, that I could just denote $F(x)$ similar to $F(x) = \{\underline F(x), \bar F(x)\}$

Answer (score 0):

You can introduce the characteristic function of a set: $$\chi_E(x)=\begin{cases}1,&x\in E,\\0,&x\notin E,\end{cases}$$and then write $F(x)=\chi_{(\tilde x,\infty)}(x)\bar F(x)+ (1-\chi_{(\tilde x,\infty)}(x))\underline F(x)$.

Another approach would be to use the Heavyside function: $$H(x)=\begin{cases}1,&x>0,\\0,&x\le 0,\end{cases}$$ to write

$$F(x) = H(x-\tilde x)\bar F(x)+  (1-H(x-\tilde x))\underline F(x) .$$